# Creating keyboard shortcuts with pynput listener

Tags: python, multithreading, keyboard, shortcut, pynput

I am trying to create a script that when activating hotkey listens for the next key pressed and looks for it in a dictionary to return a value. When I debug it works correctly, but when I do the normal run it does not respond correctly, I think it is due to thread handling, but I don't know how to solve it.

```
import keyboard
import ast
from pynput import keyboard as kb

keyboard_events={}
path = 'D:\\shortcuts.ini'
file = open(path, 'r')
content = file.read()
keyboard_events = ast.literal_eval(content)
current = set()

def on_activate():
    print('Global hotkey activated!')
    try:
        c = keyboard.read_key()
    except:
        print()
    if c in keyboard_events:
        print(keyboard_events[c])
        keyboard.write(keyboard_events[c])


def for_canonical(f):
    return lambda k: f(l.canonical(k))

hotkey = kb.HotKey(
    kb.HotKey.parse('<ctrl>+<shift>'),
    on_activate)
with kb.Listener(
        on_press=for_canonical(hotkey.press),
        on_release=for_canonical(hotkey.release)) as l:
    l.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED, the problem was not the threads, but using the hotkeys, the keys were "pressed". I share the solution
'''

```
import keyboard
import ast
from pynput import keyboard as kb
import time

keyboard_events={}
path = 'shortcuts.ini'
file = open(path, 'r')
content = file.read()
keyboard_events = ast.literal_eval(content)
current = set()

def on_activate():
    time.sleep(0.1)
    keyboard.press_and_release('ctrl')
    keyboard.press_and_release('shift')
    time.sleep(0.1)
    c = keyboard.read_key()

    if c == 'ctrl' or 'mayusculas':
        c = keyboard.read_key()

    if c in keyboard_events:
        keyboard.press('backspace')
        keyboard.write(keyboard_events[c])


def for_canonical(f):
    return lambda k: f(l.canonical(k))

hotkey = kb.HotKey(
    kb.HotKey.parse('<ctrl>+<shift>'),
    on_activate)
with kb.Listener(
        on_press=for_canonical(hotkey.press),
        on_release=for_canonical(hotkey.release)) as l:
    l.join()
```

'''